# Symfony2 and Doctrine - @ORM\PostPersist() does not work

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload, doctrine-orm

I have a file upload function on my Symfony2 project.
I used the http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html as example.

The problem is that my @ORM\PostPersist() is not trigered and my file is not stored in the specific folder.

Here is what I have:

1 Entity "Manuscript" where I will manage the file:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\PostPersist()
 * @ORM\PostUpdate()
 */
public function upload()
{
    if (null === $this->file) {
        return;
    }

    $this->file->move( $this->getUploadRootDir().date('Ymdhis').'_'.$this->file->getClientOriginalName() );
}
```

I tryed to put a var_dump() there but the var_dump() was never actioned, so I am never entering there.

In my form, I have the file:

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('file', 'file', array('label'=> 'HTM File', 'required' => true));
}
```

Finally, in the controller, I have

```
if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {

        $form->bind($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em_scipub->persist($enquiry);  
            $em_scipub->flush();
            ....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed the issue, the think I forgot to add is @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks

So, in the Manuscript entity, it should look something like that:

```
/**
* Manuscripts
*
* @ORM\Table(name="manuscripts")
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
* 
*/

class Manuscript
{
  ....
```